# Handling Double values on CUDA ( Compute Capability 1.1)

Tags: cuda, compute-capability

My code is calculating 3D-DCT, for a large set of data.

It's running on GeForce 9400M, compute capability 1.1 (which does not support double precision as far as I know).

Is there a way to enable it, or to handle the values correctly?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use double precision?

Comment: See njuffa's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769881/emulate-double-using-2-floats for a good answer (the gist is to use two floats to approximate a double)